# Access control on Cisco router with switchports?

Tags: cisco, vlan, acl

I am working with a series 800 router which has inbuilt switchports.

I want to use 2 switchports for a VLAN (say VLAN 100).

On one port will have devices:

- 192.168.1.10
- 192.168.1.30

Connected to the other port will be:

- 192.168.1.50

I want:

- 192.168.1.10 to be only able to talk to 192.168.1.50
- 192.168.1.30 to be only able to talk to an IP on another network (say 10.1.1.1)

looking at the options, I cannot seem to find a way of applying an ACL like you usually would on a Cisco Switch (at interface level). So the next level is a VACL, which appears to be OK to use.

What I want to know is, will the VACL give me the segregation I require? or is there a better way to segregate traffic as I require?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer focuses on the following part:

> or is there a better way to segregate traffic as I require?

Overall, it might turn out to be easier to run two internal VLANs with each their SVI (`interface vlan XXX`) with each their own subnet, and accepting the (possibly still small) disadvantage of having to renumber some hosts.

If you do, instead of trying to use a feature restricted built-in *switch*'s functionality, you can resort to the "classic" and more flexible features the *router* has to offer: interface access lists, CBAC firewall, ZoneBasedFirewall (ZBFW), etc.